# How to make three buttons in one line span the entire page?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the three buttons span the entire page equally, does anybody know how?

```html
<div class="mainNavigation">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form action="webPages/index.html">
          <input type="submit" value="Purchase Used Cubes" />
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="webPages/index.html">
          <input type="submit" value="Purchase Cube Products" />
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="webPages/index.html">
          <input type="submit" value="Purchase Cube Repairs" />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is the image of what the page looks like:
[image: Image of what the page looks like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width of `table` and `input` to `100%`. A bit of explanation, setting the width of `table` to `100%` makes it span across the page giving the `input` children of it equal width of `(100/3)%` (3 input elements) of the page width. Now setting the `input` width to `100%` makes it span across the available space for it, which is `(100/3)%` of the page width.

```css
table,
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainNavigation">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form action="webPages/index.html">
          <input type="submit" value="Purchase Used Cubes" />
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="webPages/index.html">
          <input type="submit" value="Purchase Cube Products" />
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="webPages/index.html">
          <input type="submit" value="Purchase Cube Repairs" />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

> Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/geekyquentin/pen/WNMEwQr

Answer (score -1):

Try using this snippet it will do the job:

```css
table,
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

But I suggest you use something like CSS grid, or flexbox for a better layout unless you have an engineering requirement.

If you want I can give you a good solution to it